# Font rendering on Blink Engine browsers

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I have an issue with browser's font look very clunky, this exists on all browser use Blink engine, so far : Opera 22, Chrome, Vivaldi.

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit. Any pointers on this problem ?

Picture related, top is Chrome, bottom is Opera 12

[image]

Comment: What version of Chrome?  Chrome 40 has significant font rendering changes.

Comment: May have been caused by a font replacement, try the steps on http://supunlivera.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/chrome-display-issue-blurry-text.html